# Nhibernate 3 - LINQ Issues

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

my application has the following code to add a ToSortedList extension method on any IEnumberable:

```
public class SortedList<T, TResult> : List<T> {
    public SortedList(IEnumerable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> sortBy, SortDirection sortDirection) {
        Initialize(source is IQueryable<T> ? source as IQueryable<T> : source.AsQueryable(), sortBy, sortDirection);
    }

    protected void Initialize(IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> sortBy, System.Web.UI.WebControls.SortDirection sortDirection) {
        AddRange(sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? source.OrderBy(sortBy) : source.OrderByDescending(sortBy));
    }
}

public static class SortingExtensions {
    public static SortedList<T, TResult> ToSortedList<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> sortBy, SortDirection sortDirection) {
        return new SortedList<T, TResult>(source, sortBy, sortDirection);
    }
}
```

In the old LINQ provider (on top of NHibernate 2.1) i could then say:

```
session.Linq<Article>().ToSortedList(a => a.Date, SortDirection.Ascending);
```

However using the new in-built LINQ provider in NHibernate 3 (change Linq to Query above) this does not work and the following error is thrown:

"Specified method is not supported." - within the Initialize method

I'd really appreciate it if someone could show me how this could be done.

Comment: can you put the stack trace for where the exception is being thrown from in nhibernate? i have an idea of what the cause is, but i thought it threw a different exception, and usually i only see it w/ extension method used inside query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble i had is that i was doing a Take before an OrderBy which unfortunately threw an exception with the release. I simplified my example and guess i missed the most important part. This has been resolved in a later build.

Answer (score 2):

In the new provider you should use session.**Query**(), Linq is an extension method from NHibernate.Linq.dll. You should delete this dll when working with nh3.

So your example should be something like:

```
session.Query<Article>().ToSortedList(a => a.Date, SortDirection.Ascending);
```

A side note; you are using SortDirection ffrom WebControls, my advice is to use ListSortDirection from componentmodel
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.listsortdirection(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use:

```
var articles =
    session.QueryOver<Article>()
        .OrderBy(a => a.Date).Asc
        .List();
```

See: http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html

Comment: Cheers for your answer but my example has been simplified.  It's far too late for me to make a change like this as i would have to do it in 100's of places.

Comment: You could extend IQueryable and add the same pattern as you have above?

Comment: Possibly but i figured since IQueryable inherits from IEnumerable i would keep things more generic so i can apply my extension method to any IEnumerable.  The trouble is this worked before with the old LINQ provider but doesn't in NHibernate 3.